# how can i avoid OOMs error in AWS Glue Job in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am getting this error while running AWS Glue job using 40 workers and processing 40GB data

`Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: error while calling spill() on org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter@5fa14240 : No space left on device`

How can i optimize my job to avoid such error on pyspark

Here is the pic of metrics
[glue_metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vzH7.png)

Comment: type of worker used?

Comment: G.1X (Recommended for memory intensive jobs) @PrabhakarReddy

Comment: Have you tried G2.X workers? Each G2.X worker has 32GB memory, which is twice the memory of a G1.X worker. Also, enable job metrics (it's under monitoring options when you edit the job in the console) and look at the "Job Execution: Active Executors, Completed Stages & Maximum Needed Executors" metric after you execute the job. Compare the maximum needed executors to the active executors. If max needed > active, your job could benefit from additional workers.

Comment: I run it on standard and G2.X workers also, same results. @jscott, I am not getting what is wrong. Even in metrics, there is 50% usage and 50% load on cpu

Comment: Look at the `glue.driver.ExecutorAllocationManager.executors.numberMaxNeededExecutors` and `glue.driver.ExecutorAllocationManager.executors.numberAllExecutors` CloudWatch metrics for your job execution. If numberAllExecutors is low, you're not using all of the workers you're assigning and your job needs to be more parallelizable. You get 1 executer per worker with G1.X and G2.X. If numberMaxNeededExecutors > numberAllExecutors, you can add workers to parallelize your job further.

Comment: @jscott Adding 80 workers and memory usage is hardly 60%(avg), what is the point of adding more workers ?

Comment: @jscott Glue `Job Execution: Active Executors, Completed Stages & Maximum Needed Executors` graph is showing number of active and required executors are 0.

Comment: @shubhamkakran did you expand the time scale to include a time period where the job was running? 0/0 is unexpected, it sounds like the job wasn't running during the time period you had graphed.

Comment: @jscott I am using native spark to run the jobs on Glue, it is not creating the metrics related to `Job Execution: Active Executors, Completed Stages & Maximum Needed Executors` and `Data Shuffle Across Executors`. I found no cloudwatch metrics

Answer (score 1):

AWS Glue Spark shuffle manager with Amazon S3

Requires using Glue 2.0

See the following links.

- https://awscloudfeed.com/whats-new/big-data/introducing-amazon-s3-shuffle-in-aws-glue
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-shuffle-manager.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31763798)

Comment: I have practiced EMR and state machines, got to know much more, now i can have more control over spark configuration. Better than Glue for longer jobs.